# Decaying solution and periodic-$1$ solution to $y''(x)=y(x)-y(x)^2$

Tags: asymptotics, dynamical-systems, perturbation-theory

I came across a problem in the dynamic systems theory, which is very similar to the following simple example.

Consider the simple model equation
$$
y''(x)=y(x)-y(x)^2. \tag{*}$$
Let us denote by $y_\infty(x)$ the solution to $(*)$ satisfying the initial conditions
$$
y(0)=\frac{3}{2},\quad y'(0)=0.$$
Then by integration, it is not hard show that
$$
y_\infty(x)=\frac{3}{2}\text{sech}^2(\frac{x}{2}),$$
where $\text{sech}(x)=2/(e^{x}+e^{-x})$ is the hyperbolic secant function.

On the other hand. Let $L>0$ be a real number, and denote by $y_L(x)$ be the solution to $(*)$ subject to the boundary conditions
$$
y'(0)=y'(L)=0.$$
We also require that $y_L'(x)\neq 0$ for $0<x<L$.

Numeric calculations seem to suggest that when $L$ is large, say $L\geq 4$, we have the estimate
$$
|y_L(0)-y_\infty(0)|\leq Ce^{-\alpha L}\tag{**}$$
for some positive constants $C$ and $\alpha$. For instance, the following table shows that some values of $|y_L(0)-y_\infty(0)|$ and $L$:
$$
\begin{array}{l l}
\hline
|y_L(0)-y_\infty(0)| & L\\
\hline
0.1 & 3.56\\
\hline
0.01 & 4.60\\
\hline
0.001 & 5.74\\
\hline
10^{-4} & 6.89\\
\hline
10^{-5}& 8.03\\
\hline
10^{-6} & 9.12\\
\hline
10^{-7} & 9.89 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

I would like to ask, is  estimate $(**)$ true? In the case that it holds, how to prove it?

Comment: Idle thought: obviously your initial conditions provide $y'(x)\rightarrow0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$. Can you integrate for any other value of $y(0)$ and possibly show exponential growth in $y'$? That might at least provide a starting point for 'running it backwards' as it were.

Comment: I tried in this direction. For other values of $y(0)$, the solutions involve elliptic integrals which I do not know how to simplify.

Comment: I think the estimate is true. We can consider this equation as a system $\dot{y} = v, \; \dot{v} = y - y^2$. It has a saddle equilibrium at $(0, 0)$ that has a homoclinic loop to it: basically, $y_{\infty}(x)$ is a time-parametrization for the solution corresponding to it. This loop encloses a region of closed trajectories and BVP $y'(0) = y'(L) = 0$ allows to select a specific trajectory. The bigger $L$ you get, the closer to homoclinic loop you become and the bigger period becomes. I guess you can adjust [this estimate](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1476548/87697) for your problem.